# Place Picker crashes in alpha test but not in android studio

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I was presented with a problem that I really can't solve !!
My app works perfectly in development environments, both on the android studio simulator and on my phone that I used for pre tests (Honor 8), but after creating the alpha test on google play I get the following error:

I press the button to launch the Picker Place, he activates himself but after a moment he closes not allowing you to select the place where you are, this problem has never occurred to me in any moment of the development and in the personal test on my phone also using it in different places since it was loaded on my phone.
I have to be honest that my API key has been active for more than 1 year but for personal problems I could not continue the development, do you think that this could interfere with the correct APK operation of the API?

Checking in the Google API Dashboard the key is working and active.

Here I report my manifest and the code I use to call my Piker:

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.miapp.miapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@ApiKey" />
        <activity android:name=".Find_Place">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OkRes_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".PutIn_Activity"/>
        <activity android:name=".utilityBOperation" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Call Piker:

```
placeNameText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Find_Place:placeNameText.setOnClickListener: OnCreate : Ho cliccato la mia Text");

                //Richiamo il costruttore del mio Piker
                Log.v(TAG, "Find_Place:placeNameText.setOnClickListener: Start....... Richiamo il Piker con IntentBuilder....");
                IntentBuilder builder = new IntentBuilder();
                try {
                    Intent intent = builder.build(Find_Place.this);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Find_Place: OnCreate : Builder : Start....... Lancio il mio builder nell'activity....");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sto chiamando il piker ed attendendo il risultato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    String message;
                    message = e.getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Find_Place: OnCreate : Builder : C'è stato un errore .... " + e);
                }

            }
        });
```

I check the result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //  Popolo la mia texviView con i miei dati
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sono nel onActivityResult ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.v(TAG,"Find_Place: OnCreate : onActivityResult : Gestisco il risultato del Piker  .... " );
    if (requestCode== PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sono nel onActivityResult: requestCode== PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST" + PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG, "Find_Place:onActivityResult: Valore del requestCode== PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST " + PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sono nel onActivityResult: resultCode == RESULT_OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "Find_Place:onActivityResult: Valore del resultCode........." + resultCode);
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(Find_Place.this, data);
```

I can't add error logs because even from the google play consol there aren't any crashes.
I can't really understand what the problem is if you can help me!
While I am there, I add this question, according to you it may cause problems that I have inserted all the processes into the onActivityResult so that if the Picker is not activated it cannot be continued?

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I managed to solve it by myself and write the solution below to help anyone who finds the same problem.
The poroblema arises from the fact that we create an api key that we are going to insert into our code but which only serves as a test key. When we go to create our ALPHA or BETA the Google Play Console automatically generates an API key to insert into our GOOGLE DEVELOPERS CONSOLE together with our API key generated during the creation of the APP, this will allow us to use the API requested in the our app in development version.
IMPORTANT
The new API key not replaced by the old one should be added, otherwise it will no longer be possible to use the API in the development environment.

I hope it will be useful.